# Passport Authorization Does Not Authorize User In Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 and Passport for API. And currently I have this route:

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function(){
    Route::post('login', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\UserController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('register', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\UserController::class, 'register']);

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/user' , function () {
            return auth()->user();
        });
        Route::post('/comment' , [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\CommentController::class, 'store']);
});
```

Now I can correctly send a request on Postman and register a new user and gets the `api_token`.

But when I send a POST request on `/comment` url, and also adding the Headers like this:

[image]

I get this message:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Meaning that the user is not yet authenticated. However as you can see in the picture, I have properly added the `api_token` with `Bearer` as `Authorization`.

So what is going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'api_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'api_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider:**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set up the driver correctly ? did you try getting the user ? '/user'

Comment: @HijenHEK Driver is: `'driver' => 'passport',` and `/users` shows  {"message":"Unauthenticated."} !

Comment: Do you want to show us your `User` model? Also how did you generate that token?

Comment: @RobertTirta Of course, I just added it, if you want to look at anything else such as Controllers or Resources, just let me know, thx

Comment: 1 more please, can you show us the content of your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`

Comment: @RobertTirta I just added it

Comment: php artisan optimize:clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to setup [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#get-oauthclients):

Install passport:

```
composer require laravel/passport
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install
```

Add traits to user model:

`use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;`

Setup `AuthServiceProvider` (You're missing this step):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        
        // MISSING HERE
        if (!$this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            Passport::routes();
        }
    }
}
```

To add to the answer, in your case if you want to get a token with a password grant. These are the steps:

1. Create a client

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

2. Get the client id and secret, then make a request in your postman to your app at this endpoint `http://yourapp.com/oauth/token`, and payload:

```
{
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': 'client-id',
    'client_secret': 'client-secret',
    'username': 'myusername@email.com',
    'password': 'my-password',
    'scope': '*',
}
```

3. Then you can use your `access_token` returned from passport to request to your api

Comment: I tried it, but still get the `"message": "Unauthenticated."` :(

Comment: Where did you get your token?

Comment: I goto phpmyadmin and get the `api_token` of user and copy and pasted at Authorization key

Comment: he got the token without auth , the weird thing here is that you gave him default routes , did he access it with the same prefix ? and still got unauthenticated ?

Comment: It used to be working fine and I could add comment correctly via POST request

Comment: wait what ? you have a route for that

Comment: you shouldnt take them directly from the db ! please read the docs

Comment: You need to get the token via the endpoint, assuming you're getting it from table `oauth_access_tokens`, those tokens are generated automatically and may be expired. not sure where'd you get yours, but try to follow the instruction above to generate tokens from password @tejoslaeslio

Comment: Plz would mind take a look at this question, my career depends on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605266/how-to-read-smart-contracts-from-tronscan-org-using-laravel-and-json-rpc